# How to keep Linux running after hard drive removal?

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, kernel

I am working on an embedded Linux device with a USB hard drive. There is a swap file on this drive. The hard drive may be powered down at any moment before being powered back on few seconds later. This leads to various error messages, such as:

```
Write-error on swap-device
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

or exceptions in various applications, which is understandable since some page in/out requests failed.
(Note that this kernel panic is also reproducible on a regular desktop Linux).

My goal is to somehow prevent this from happening and recover the system without rebooting the OS.

I can postpone the crash by calling `scsi_block_requests`, but I cannot keep them blocked forever.

I tried to kill some user mode tasks (using `send_sig_info`) in response to `USB_DEVICE_REMOVE` notification, but still keep getting exceptions.

I am also thinking whether it is possible to prevent SCSI device from being destroyed when USB device is removed, but keep it around and then somehow reconnect it to the new USB device, which will be created few seconds later when USB device is powered again. Since this is the same disk, then maybe I can resume all pending requests without re-mounting the disk.

What is your opinion? Can something like that be done? Or is it impossible to cleanly recover OS after hard drive removal?

Comment: Do you *really* need a swap partition on that volume?

Comment: How about not having a swap file at all? If you've got enough RAM, you're fine. If you don't, you are screwed anyway.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you end up with a swap drive on a USB disk? The only things less suited for a swap drive I can think of would be a memory stick or a floppy.

Comment: Swap or no swap, if any binaries are loaded from the drive that disappears he may also run into problems.  So don't load code from that drive either.

Comment: @asveikau true... But a swap adds an extra dimension to it as anything, even things not living on that drive could be swapped out (to a rather high cost).

Comment: Alas, one application requires more RAM than I have and USB is the only drive available. It would be OK to kill that app when drive is disconnected, but it does not die gracefully, but crashes, and kernel panics as well.

Comment: @jhnlmn (and closers) - is this question because you're writing an app for the embedded system and trying to control the system? I ask because this question does seem on-topic to me. Unfortunately, I think your best solution is hardware or maybe a kernel patch.

Comment: My question was about kernel/driver programming, so it does not belong to superuser.com. I hoped to hear an opinion of kernel experts. However, some answers, such as compcache, may be useful for users as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just killing the application that uses more RAM than you have won't guarantee that the swap file becomes unused. If that app had been running, its memory demands could have caused any other process to have had some of its pages swapped out to the swap device. Killing the memory hungry process won't bring those pages back until they are reloaded.

One possibility would be to do away with the kernel level swap device, and rewrite the problematic process so that rather than `malloc`ing more memory than the system has access to and relying on the kernel to handle swap, just `mmap` the USB device (or a file on the device if the device is also used for other things) and manually handle your memory needs in userspace that go beyond the available memory (effectively implement an additional heap that lives on your USB Device). Then when the device needs to go away, simply killing or suspending that process will be enough to prevent the system from trying to access the device.

Comment: +1:  a very good engineering solution--if the application can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider would be [compcache](http://code.google.com/p/compcache/), which compresses memory pages, utilizing your RAM more efficiently so you don't need a swap file.  Aside from that, the only way you are going to be able to solve your issue is by some hardcore hacking of the swapping code in the kernel.